# Install Magento 2 with MAMP

Tags: magento2, composer, magento2-dev-beta

I have MAMP & MAMP PRO.

I tried to install Magento 2 beta. When i write "composer install" the system returns  me this error:

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - The requested PHP extension ext-mcrypt * is missing from your system.

I have check the services of system and mcrypt is enabled.

How i can solve?

Thanks

Comment: enable the mcrypt php extension

Comment: as I said just above, the extension mcrypt is active

Comment: If composer says it's not, then it's not. Maybe you have 2 php versions.

Comment: I have the same problem too, the problem is magenta is using macOS's php instead of php install on MAMP

Comment: it is probable, but how do I do recognize a composer the php of MAMP?

Comment: use `which php` on your terminal to find out what php are you using.

Comment: also look with ```php -m``` which modules are active via cli, and with ```php --ini``` which ini files are loaded

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a file called .bash_profile on your home directory (if you don't have this file already), and add this to the file:

```
export PATH=/Applications/mamp/bin/!YOUR-PHP-VERSION!/bin:$PATH
```

@ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857068/change-the-php-path-to-mamps-php

Comment: make sure you fill in your php version, you can get this info at phpinfo on mamp start page.

Comment: if you are still running in to some problem, try change the php version on mama's version in the preference,

Comment: I am using 1.6.2 and it works fine for me.

Comment: The easiest approach I found was to add a symlink of current PHP into `/usr/local/bin/php` in this way I'm forcing composer to use the php i need.